# How to solve a large set of multivariate compound linear inequality in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, scientific-computing

I'm working on trying to implement Dinur-Nissim algorithm and am stuck at how to solve the set of linear inequalities with multiple unknowns and a large number of equations along with constraints.

Example:
0.2<=c4<=0.66

0.66<=c3<=1.56

0.96<=c3+c4<=2.26

Constraints:
0<=ci<=1

and many other equations with the no of unknowns going till cn where n is the size of the database, so I need a solution which works for a large number of equations.

I've tried to look for some libraries but most of them solve Maximization or Minimization problems so am not sure if its possible to convert these equations to one of those problems.

Comment: In your example I can see only constraints and no equations. Are you looking for a feasible region or an individual solution? What about ambiguities in the latter case? (e.g. `c3=0.7, c4=0.6` and `c3=0.9, c4=0.2` both solve the example, which solution is preferrable?) Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @kazemakase Yes am looking for feasible regions, basically the last step involves making a decision based on the value of c, if ci>1/2 then xi=1 else xi=0, so I just need to find the region of c's which satisfy the inequalities.
I tried http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/11/solving-a-linear-programming-problem-with-python-pulp/   but since I don't really have a maximization or minimization problem, I tried maximizing c1+c2+c3+....+cn but it doesn't give the desired answer, so basically the question is I just need to find the feasible regions of c's

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach using scipy's linprog (Linear Programming; LP is probably the most specific/powerful optimization-problem-type usable here!):

#### Code

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

c = [0, 0, 0, 0]                            # empty objective
A = [[0, 0, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, -1, -1], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
b = [-0.2, 0.66, -0.66, 1.56, -0.96, 2.26]

result = linprog(c, A, b, bounds=(0,1))
print(result)
```

#### Output

```
fun: -0.0
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nit: 3
slack: array([ 0.1 ,  0.9 ,  1.3 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.34,  0.7 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ])
status: 0
success: True
  x: array([ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.66,  0.3 ])
```

The above is a basic usage of linprog:

- we don't need any objective and therefore keep all factors zero (see `c`)
- we need the form `Ax <= b` for our inequalities:

  - `0.96 <= c3+c4 <=> c3+c4 >= 0.96 <=> -c3 -c4 <= 0.96`

Keep in mind, that linprog is not as stable as commercial solvers. You could solve this problem also with SLSQP.

The above, in combination with your description:

> basically the last step involves making a decision based on the value of c, if ci>1/2 then xi=1 else xi=0, so I just need to find the region of c's which satisfy the inequalities

makes not much sense in the *general-case*, as the optimization, as described in your post, returns a feasible value and without additional modelling, the solver does not care about your threshold of 0.5. So you should check your theory again (i did not check out your algorithm to implement; maybe the nature of the problem allows for this approach).